# FOREIGN KEY mysql error

Tags: mysql, database, key

Getting error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (Epost) REFERENCES KUNDE (Epost)) ENGINE = INNODB' at line 9
```

This is code:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDRE (
    OrdreNr INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Dato DATE,
    Antall INT,
    Pris INT,
    PNr INT,
    Epost VARCHAR(32),
    FOREIGN KEY (PNr)   REFERENCES PRODUKT (PNr)
    FOREIGN KEY (Epost) REFERENCES KUNDE (Epost)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

What is the issue of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot comma

```
  Epost VARCHAR(32),
FOREIGN KEY (PNr)   REFERENCES PRODUKT (PNr),
                                            ^---you forgot this comma
FOREIGN KEY (Epost) REFERENCES KUNDE (Epost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDRE (
    OrdreNr INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Dato DATE,
    Antall INT,
    Pris INT,
    PNr INT,
    Epost VARCHAR(32),
    FOREIGN KEY (PNr)   REFERENCES PRODUKT (PNr),
    FOREIGN KEY (Epost) REFERENCES KUNDE (Epost)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

There is a comma missing.